# Convert File to FileItem Using Scala

Tags: scala, file, junit, scalatra, fileitem

I have a web UI that accepts a file uploaded as **scalatra.servlet.FileItem** and is passed to several functions that do something with the file uploaded. This is working properly. Now, I need to make a junit test for this feature. With this junit test, the file no longer needs to be uploaded. I only have to read it from a location.

```
val inFile = new File("resources/sample.xml")
```

My problem is that i need to pass this to the function that accepts FileItem as parameter. I get a Type mismatch error. How do i change this to FileItem? I have looked at several articles but none worked. I'm wondering if it is even possible to convert from File to FileItem. I have also tried using

```
val fileItem = new DiskFileItem("payloadFile", "plain/text", false, "Payload_FileItem", availableBytes, inFile).asInstanceOf[org.scalatra.servlet.FileItem]
```

but this still had error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem cannot be cast to org.scalatra.servlet.FileItem
```

I also tried using inputStreams but don't know what to do next to convert from the stream to FileItem (or if it is even possible).

```
val inputStream = getSystemClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("resources/sample.xml")
```

Hope anyone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lot of confusion here; as there are actually two classes around - the apache ones, but then that scala framework has its **own** version of things.

See [here](https://github.com/utaal/small-scalatra-core/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/servlet/FileUploadSupport.scala#L220) - FileUploadSupport.scala defines its **own** class

```
case class FileItem(part: Part) {
```

So it looks like you actually could create instances of that class directly - if you manage to figure what that **part** parameter is about.

My idea to get to an answer - figure the full name of that Part parameter; and then see if you can use that knowledge to directly instantiate such an instance of org.scalatra.servlet.FileItem from there.